# Variable as Interface or Interface[] type

Tags: javascript, typescript, interface

In this code:

```
insert1(data: iFlower) {
    ...
    return data;
}

insert2(data: iFlower[]) {
    ...
    return data;
}

public insert (data: iFlower | iFlower[]) {
    if (data as iFlower) {
        return this.insert1(data as iFlower);
    }
    else if (data as iFlower[]) {
        return this.insert2(data as iFlower[]);
    }
```

when I call the `insert()` function, depending on the type the variable `data` has, I want to call one method or the other. But in this case, if `data` is an array of objects (`iFlower[]` type), it still enters in the `insert1` function... Or better said, even if `data` is of `iFlower` or `iFlower[]` type, it will call the same method.

How can I solve this? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`as` is a typescript operator that can be used to typecast types. It does not make any checks at runtime, therefore it is useless. Your code basically does this at runtime:

```
 if(data /*as iFlower*/) // data is truthy, enters branch
```

You could use `Array.isArray` to determine wether the passed value is an array:

```
 if (Array.isArray(data)) // iFlower[]
```